# Parsing a space delimited string of integers into a filtered array of intergers

Tags: java

I have read in a string with a list of numbers. I then have created an array with the length of 3. My question, is how do I get the numbers from the string into the array (It's okay if there are more or fewer than 3 numbers > 11).

I have tried going through the string sequentially and putting the values into the output array but that hasn't worked. I have also tried making the output array a String array but that also proved to be incorrect.

```
    public int[] findNums(String line)
{
    int[] array = new int[3];
    list = line;
    String[] parts = array.split(" ");
    int index = 0;
    for(int spot=0; spot<parts.length();spot++)
    {
        if(parts[spot] > 11)
        {
            array[index] = spot;
            index++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

This is my method that I have so far as you can see I have a loop that goes through the string and the if-statement to check the value of the digit. 
There might be some syntax errors(sorry in advance) I'm new to arrays in Java.
Here's an example of the DAT file i am bringing in.

```
-99 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12345
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -99
10 20 30 40 50 -11818 40 30 21 10 
32767
250 19 17 15 13 11 10 9 6 3 2 1 -455
255 255
```

the output of the new array should be

```
[12345,0,0]
```

Since there is only one number greater than 11.

This is the output for the first line but it is the same format for all lines within the DAT file.

Can someone tell my how i should fix my method?

Comment: javascript is not java

Comment: sorry i saw someone tell me the opposite. thanks for the tip though! I'll make the change ASAP. @quirimmo

Comment: btw, split the string by spaces and get an array of values, then filter all the values of this array which are greater than 11

Comment: I already changed the tag for you, so some java guy will fix your code. Whoever told you that JavaScript is the same as Java, please do not listen to him anymore, whoever he is :)

Comment: so something like  `String[] cut = line.split(" ");` ?

Comment: so many things wrong here - you shouldn't be using "spot" in `if(spot> 11)` if you are looking for numbers from your list that are greater than 11. That is only if it's the 11th iteration. 

if the set of numbers were 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 110 120 130 140 150, you would only get 140 and 150. Likewise, you need a check for once three spots have been filled, or you will run in to an error trying to assign an index that can't exist.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why return a 3 element index when there is only 1 value > 11?  What if there are more than 3 values > 11?

Comment: @AndrewS that i because i will have other inputs that have more than one number greater than 11. but also i only need 3 for the output. If there are more than 3 values then the method should be able to skip over them.

Comment: If there is only 1 element > 11 then why not return a 1 element array?  If there is more than 3 elements then return a 3 element array.  This would enable the use of streams, with a mapping function, filter, and limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice solution:

```
public int[] getNumsFromString (String text) {
    String[] individNums = text.split(" ");
    int[] nums = new int[3];

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < individNums.length; i++) {
        int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(individNums[i]);
        if (currentValue > 11 && counter < 3) {
            nums[counter++] = currentValue;
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks this does help a lot! all i need to do is add the if-statement to return the value i need!

Comment: Glad to help. Thinking simply is always the way to go ;). Edit: make sure to replace the `i < 3` in the for loop with `i < individNums.length`

Answer (score 0):

I need to confirm if your goal is to pull all the numbers which have a value greater than 11 from the list passed in? You seem to be confusing your index for the value. If what you really want is all entries 11 or greater try this. You aren't instantiating the list variable correctly, if it's a comma separated list you'll need to use the split function as mentioned by the commenter above.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> findNums(String line)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> twelvePlus = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
    for(int index=0; index<numbers.length;index++)
    {
        if(Integer.valueOf(numbers[index]) > 11)
        {
            twelvePlus.add(new Integer(Integer.valueOf(numbers[index])));
            index++;
        }
    }
    return twelvePlus;
}
```

...it returns a variable number of numbers, which represent all numbers greater than eleven from the list you passed in. If you want to enforce an upper limit you can add a break statement inside the condition based on the size of the array list. Do you really want the zeros? Does it have to be an integer array return value? My example illustrates the use of generics. Also, guessing you never hit the condition because you havea type mismatch error...

Comment: Thank you but the output needed is incorrect. The output has to be `[12345,0,0]`. Thanks for the help though i really do apprecieate it